# Setting and getting a boolean object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

So I just submitted my very first pull request on a collaborative software project (a web app built with Ember.js), and I noticed that I had carelessly included a boolean variable (conditionally set inside a function) in an object literal *using only the variable name* rather than a key-value pair, like so:

```
function fruitStand () {
  // do something here to decide if this basket is pretty, and if not..
  var prettyBasket = false;

  var myObj = {
    apples : 1,
    oranges : 2,
    prettyBasket
  };

  return myObj;

}
```

I was surprised that accessing the boolean later with

```
var stand = fruitStand();
var truthy = stand.prettyBasket;
```

seems to work, but is this valid JavaScript? Otherwise poor form? Setting it with something like `prettyBasket : prettyBasket` feels less DRY if the above is OK.

Comment: If you're submitting code to public projects, it's probably a good idea to run it through a linter with settings to constrain the level of JS spec that they accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unintentionally utilizing a feature of ES6, specifically shorthand object literal notation, which you can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Also, depending on whether or not the application you are working on is built with Ember-cli (and is using an ES6 transpiler) or you are building a regular Ember application (potentially without transpilation), you should be cognizant that only the latest browsers will support that code unless it is being transpiled to standard object literal notation.